# What to include for Qt5?

Tags: visual-studio, qt, include, qt5

I've just moved my project from Qt4 to Qt5 and I have problem with includes.

For Qt4, I used these lines:

```
#include <QtGui\QtGui>
#include <QtCore\QtCore>
```

But this doesn't work for Qt5 and I don't know what I should use. In QtCreator's examples I can see them using QtWidgets, but I use MS Visual Studio and including works a bit differently there.

Comment: See: https://wiki.qt.io/Transition_from_Qt_4.x_to_Qt5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never needed to use those includes. If you are including the entire `QtGui` module, it already includes the `QtCore` it depends on, and in either Qt 4 or Qt 5 you **only** need `#include <QtGui>`. The prefix form `<QtModule/QClass>` is never necessary.

Since widgets moved out of the gui module in Qt 5, you need to simply `#include <QtWidgets>` in Qt 5. Or, if you wish to support both Qt 4 and Qt 5:

```
#include <QtGui>
#if QT_VERSION >= QT_VERSION_CHECK(5,0,0)
#include <QtWidgets>
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks, it works with QtWidgets. But for some reason I need to use it like this: #include <QtWidgets\QtWidgets>

Comment: @ni1ight No, you don't. You had a stale Makefile from a `.pro` file that didn't have `QT += widgets`. Delete the build folder and retry.

Answer (score 1):

1) It's not recommended to include those headers for the module, it's much better to include only the headers that you need (and use forward declaration instead of include whenever you can). Including the module headers will increase the compilation speed (it can be by a lot, depending on how big is your project).

2) You shouldn't need the path in include, instead of `#include<QtWidgets/QLabel>` you can use: `#include <QLabel>` and it should work, if Qt is properly installed.

3) [QtWidgets](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-module.html) is a module in Qt5 that contains the C++ ui elements (QLabel and so on) that were in gui module in Qt4 ([gui module](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtgui-index.html) now holds just some basics about window system, events, opengl, images, etc), so you need to link QtWidgets module if you create ui in C++, by adding `QT += widgets` in your .pro file (if you use Qt Creator) or by selecting it in Modules tab of the Qt Project settings (if you use VS ide).

You can see more about modules in the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmodules.html).